# Where is social media info located in salesforce database?

Tags: api

I am developing a Canvas App for Salesforce and I got stucked in a point.

When I request API "/sobjects/Contact/" that have a twitter account associated with, that twitter information did not came into the response.

Where I can locate that info? Is there another sobject with it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Fellipe. Have you looked through the Enterprise WSDL? If not, where have you looked to find the fields? And does the target org even have that enabled?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, as of this time there is no way to access that information. It is stored on the [SocialPersona](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=social_customer_service_socialpersona.htm&language=th) internal object.

See the following post for some additional information: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/2032/411