# Can I grab the Social Accounts and Contacts Images?

Tags: api, social-content

I've enabled Social Accounts and Contacts in our org, and now I'd like to grab that image from Salesforce via API to display on our external website. I'm particularly interested in the Twitter image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer:

[Is it possible to connect a social networking profile to a custom object record?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-social-networking-profile-to-a-custom-object-record/2032#2032)

The gist of it is that you can't query for that object via SOQL right now, so you unfortunately can't pull any of that data for your own use.